# python PIL image.open() error

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

hello i'm using PIL to open images but there are such errors like this; 
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/Users/minsw0810gmail.com/Desktop/GUIAccidentAlarm.py", line 
142, in <module>
   filename1 = Image.open('횡단보도상_100x100.jpg', "rb")
  File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2462, in open
    raise ValueError("bad mode %r" % mode)
ValueError: bad mode 'rb'
[Finished in 0.8s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u 
"/Users/minsw0810gmail.com/Desktop/GUIAccidentAlarm.py"]
[dir: /Users/minsw0810gmail.com/Desktop]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

*횡단보도상_100x100.jpg is korean
and my code is

filename1 = Image.open('횡단보도상_100x100.jpg')

Comment: The error is self explanatory...

Answer (score 3):

Image.open() only supports "r" as mode parameters and throws an exception for everything else.

Here is what the doc says about this parameter:

> mode – The mode. If given, this argument must be “r”.

For more information here is the link:

http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open

I hope this can help you.

Comment: do you mean that i should write                                                        
       filename1 = Image.open("횡단보도상_100x100.jpg", "r")  ???

Comment: Just do not write anything except the file path

Comment: filename1 = Image.open('횡단보도상_100x100.jpg') do you mean this?

Comment: filename1 = Image.open('횡단보도상_100x100.jpg', "rb") this is what I read in the traceback. Try to rename the file with English characters probably Korean is parsed in a bad way