# can not figure out what the error is in my python

Tags: python

i really want to figure out what the error is!!!

```
ValueError: bad mode 'rb
```

and

```
import pygame
import os
import Item
global items
from PIL import Image



image = Image.open("/Users/oscar/Desktop/python_calculator/images/numbers/1.png","rb")
image.show()
one = Item.Item("/Users/oscar/Desktop/python_calculator/images/numbers/1.png",       "1",       200, 200) # here is where you specify the image file name ( must be exact!)
two = Item.Item('/images/numbers/2.png',       "2",       200, 200) # here is where you specify the image file name ( must be exact!)
three = Item.Item('/images/numbers/3.png',       "3",       200, 200) # here is where you specify the image file name ( must be exact!)
four = Item.Item('/images/numbers/4.png',       "4",       200, 200) # here is where you specify the image file name ( must be exact!)
five = Item.Item('/images/numbers/5.png',       "5",       200, 200) # here is where you specify the image file name ( must be exact!)
six = Item.Item('/images/numbers/6.png',       "6",       200, 200) # here is where yo specify the image file name ( must be exact!)
seven = Item.Item('/images/numbers/7.png',       "7",       200, 200) # here is where you specify the image file name ( must be exact!)
eight = Item.Item('/images/numbers/8.jpg',       "8",       200, 200)# here is where you specify the image file name ( must be exact!)
nine = Item.Item('/images/numbers/9.png',       "9",       200, 200)# here is where you specify the image file name ( must be exact!)
ten = Item.Item('/images/numbers/0.jpg',       "0",       200, 200)# here is where you specify the image file name ( must be exact!)
plus = Item.Item('/images/sim/+.png',       "+",       200, 200)#
minus = Item.Item('/images/sim/-.png',       "-",       200, 200)
```

with another page

```
import pygame
import os
global items
from PIL import Image



class Item():
    global hide
    # the constructor
    def __init__(fp, img_name, name, x, y):
        #pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, items)
        image = Image.open(fp,"r")
        image.show()


        name = name;
        hide = False

    # to display on game panel
    #def display(self, surface):
    #    if self.hide == False:
    #        surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python PIL image.open() error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45518335/python-pil-image-open-error)

Answer (score 1):

from [`Image.open` docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html):

> mode – The mode. If given, this argument must be “r”.

So you can't provide a `mode="rb"`

just stick with the standard `"r"`

```
image = Image.open("/Users/oscar/Desktop/python_calculator/images/numbers/1.png")
```

same as

```
image = Image.open("/Users/oscar/Desktop/python_calculator/images/numbers/1.png", "r")
```